# Can't login with my Google ID on android device?

Tags: support, login, openid, android

Having problem in login to stackoverflow with my Google ID on my android device.

> How can I login to StackOverflow on my android device?

Comment: What problems are you having? Please give enough details of it.

Comment: after tapping **"login using Google-ID"** , the page lodes for at-least 2 mins and then shows network error.

Comment: network error not related to Stack Exchange

Comment: but there is no actual network error, my net is working fine with other apps and websites

Comment: I don't think the error is related to [so], I'm logged in with my android device with my google account! (try clearing the data on your browser)

Comment: Does the SO android app log its errors somewhere?

Comment: @Andomar there's no mention of the app here. I presume the OP is talking about the mobile version of the site.

Comment: @psubsee2003 yes I am talking about the mobile version of the site...and I also tried it on the app of stackoverflow(i.e. SoClient) on the play store.

Comment: It is not a network error, the server returns a 400 Bad Request error. This happens in both Chrome and Firefox. Firefox prints the error out better, as on Chrome it's tiny text that scrolls to the left and right. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/1UclTAa.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having the '400 - Bad Request' error, this is caused by Adblock Plus running on your Android device. Disable Adblock Plus, and logins will work as intended.